# How to find out how many days left to get the Fanatic and Enthusiast badge

Tags: support

From  https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/26/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/ it says

> And remember, this is a continuous award: if you don’t visit the site
>   for a single day, that will “break” your streak, and you’ll have to
>   start over.

It says

> Enthusiast — visited the site each day for 30 days

and

> fanatic — visited the site each day for 100 days

Is there a way to find how many days one has been continuously on this? I searched my profile under "badges" and "which badge to track", but I am unable to find information about these badges in search to see how many days I've visited continuously.

Comment: it says so on your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348765/nasser?tab=profile),top right hand side

Comment: Related: *[List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67397)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are tracking a badge, or selecting a badge to track, the tracker will show you how far along you are. If you look at your user profile for the stack, in the "summary" tab, you'll see a section that looks like this:

[image: tracking badge display]

To the right of where it says "Next badge", you will see a "fraction" (3/30, in the image above); this says that you have 3 continuous days, and need a total of 30, for the "Enthusiast" badge. This is also the notation for other badges where you need a specific number of actions, even if they're not continuous or within a given period.

You will see the same indication when you select a badge, though in that case it will be "in" the badge:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find this. I went to https://stackexchange.com/users/399717/nasser  which I found by clicking on "Network profile" from my Mathematica stackexchange account page. But I do not see a "summary" tab any where there. I am actually now confused on one thing. Are these badges given per specific site? or for visiting any site one has subscribed to under stackexchange? Thanks

Comment: Each stack has its own user profile, and tracks badges separately. For this particular stack (meta.stackexchange.com), you would go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348765/nasser and then click on "Activity" in the upper left. You can also get to your profile page by clicking on your reputation score (while you're logged in) in the top bar on any stack you've joined.

Answer (score 1):

While the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303286/152859) is not wrong, you have a faster way to get what you want.

The number of consecutive days is visible (only for you) in your profile page:

> [image]

No need to track any badge to see it.

Comment: A good call, which I overlooked, but note that you'd have to _know_ what the "consecutive days" badge's requirement _is_, where using the badge tracker/selector gives you both your current progress _and_ what you need to achieve it.

Comment: @Jeff good point! :)